# php override class loaded inside class

Tags: php

My class :

```
<?php

class a {

    private static $b;

    function __construct() {
        self::$b=rand(1000,9999);
    }

    function get_c() {
        $vv= new a();
        echo $vv->get_bb();
    }

    public function get_bb() {
       return self::$b;
    }   
}
```

Then if I use it :

```
$c1  =  new a;

echo $c1->get_bb();
echo "\n";
echo $c1->get_c();
echo "\n";
echo $c1->get_bb();
echo "\n";
```

It returns :

```
4468
6007
6007   <=== WHY??  why not 4468 ?
```

My class owerwrite class......

I don't understand! Help me please!

> PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u12 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2018 13:49:38)

Answer (score 2):

In your `class a` the property `$b` is `static`. This means there's only one `$b` for all instantiations of `class a`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

So when `$c1->get_bb();` is executed for the first time, the value of `$b` is returned that was set during the global instantiation of `class a`.

Then `$c1->get_c();` is executed. This instantiations a new `class a`. This means that the static property `$b` is given a new value, since `function __construct()` is called on each instantiation.

So when `$c1->get_bb();` is executed for the second time, the value of `$b` has changed.